# node.js async each function callback failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm making a call to my db, and want to use the results to fire off a request to another server, and then handle the responses. I want to do this asynchronously so I am trying to use the async library.

```
var sendRequest = function (store) {

    console.log(store);
}

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * from stores', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err){
        async.each(rows, function(row, sendRequest) {
            var store = {id: row.id, address: row.address};
            //console.log(store); <-- this works
            sendRequest(store); <-- this logs {id: '', address: null} only once
        }, function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    else
        console.log('Error performing query');
});

connection.end();
```

If I log the store variable directly, it logs for each instance in the array rows and properly. If I try to do it through the sendRequest callback, it does it only once and improperly.

Comment: Can you tell me if you are using the nodeJS "async" library here? https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#each

Comment: @NormanBreau, yes I am. Thats the async.each function call.

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to have two variables named `sendRequest`. It can cause potential confusion making people think the `sendRequest` inside the `async.each` callback have anything to do with the `sendRequest` function at the top.

Comment: @slebetman, but I want it to call that function.

Comment: @haaduken: Ha! see! even you are confused! Then rename the other variable (the function argument) to something else to stop it from being overridden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You confused some things. You're using the same name, `sendRequest`, for the `each` callback. You should do instead:

```
connection.query('SELECT * from stores', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (!err){
    async.each(rows, function(row, callback) {
        var store = {id: row.id, address: row.address};
        sendRequest(store);
        callback();

    }, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
  }
  else
    console.log('Error performing query');
});
```

Comment: so what goes in callback and where is it defined?

Comment: @haaduken: That callback is passed to you by `async.each`, just like `row`

Comment: `callback` is an argument of the function that `async.each` has to call for each item in the array, to notify that it has finished. You can use whatever name you want, just make sure that this name is not in use by other functions or variables.